# Units in terms of subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ and $K = \mathbb Q(\zeta)$ where $ζ = e^{i\pi/6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2} $.

I have computed $$N_{K/L}(1 + \zeta)= 2 + \sqrt 3.$$

And now I want to show that
$$\mathcal O^∗_K = \{(1 + \zeta)^m u \ : \ 0 \leq m \leq 11, \ u \in \mathcal O^*_L\}.$$

This looks like Kummer's Lemma but I am unsure about how to emulate that proof here. Does anyone have advice on how to proceed?

Comment: I think you might want to include powers of $\zeta$ as well.  Do you know Dirichlet's unit theorem? By an argument on the rank and torsions, you should be able to argue that a certain set is indeed the set of units

Comment: @daruma my source is  typically accurate see question 20H here https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2013/PaperII_2.pdf

Comment: But yeah I know dirichlet's unit theorem

Comment: Your claim is obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you could compare the rank and the torsions of the unit groups in the two number fields.

Let me denote $r$ for number of real embeddings and $2s$ for the number of complex embeddings.

For $L$, $r_L=2$ and $s_L=0$. So, $rank \mathcal{O}_L^*=2+0-1=1$.

For $K$, $r_K=0$ and $s_K=2$. So, $rank \mathcal{O}_K^*=0+2-1=1$.

What this means is that the two unit groups have the same rank. So this means that $2-\sqrt{3}$, the fundamental unit for $L$ can be generated by one fundamental unit of $K$ up to a factor of the torsion.

Being a torsion means $r^n=1$ for some $n$ and in particular, it is a root of unity. $L$ has two roots of unity $\{\pm 1\}$ whilst $K$ have $\{\zeta^i: 0\leq i\leq 11\}$.

Note that $N(1-\zeta)=2-\sqrt{3}$ means $(1-\zeta)(1-\zeta^{-1})=2-\sqrt{3}$

Since $(1-\zeta^{-1})=-\zeta^{-1}(1-\zeta)$, we now know that $1-\zeta$ generates the fundamental unit for $K$, $2-\sqrt{3}$ up to a torsion.

But is $1-\zeta$ itself a fundamental unit for $K$? Could there be some other unit $w$ where $1-\zeta=w^n\zeta^m$ (where $n>1$?).

Taking norms though, this would imply $N(w)^n=2-\sqrt{3}$ with $n>1$. This would suggest that $N(w)\in \mathcal{O}_L^*$ generates $2-\sqrt{3}$ contradicting that $2-\sqrt{3}$ is a fundamental unit.

Answer (score 0):

As a first observation we have $(1+\zeta)^2 = \zeta(1+\bar\zeta)(1+\zeta) = \zeta(2+\sqrt3)$. Since $u_1:=2+\sqrt3\in\mathcal O_L^*$, your set contains $\zeta$ and in fact all the powers of $\zeta$.

By Dirichlet's unit theorem there is a fundamental unit $v\in\mathcal O_L^*$ such that $\mathcal O_L^*=\{\zeta^k v^n \mid 0\leq k\leq11, n\in\mathbb Z \}$. What we need to check is that $1+\zeta$ is, in fact, a fundamental unit.

To do it, we can use the logarithmic map(s) (see the mentioned Dirichlet's theorem). For $K$ it is $\text{Log}_K:K^*\to\mathbb R$, given by $\text{Log}_K(z) = \log(|z|^2)$ (where $z$ is seen as a complex number), and for $L$ it is $\text{Log}_L(x) =\log|x|$. (The logarithmic maps should really go to $\mathbb R^2$, but we shall only need one component, so I'm throwing out one of the $\mathbb R$'s).
We thus have
$$\text{Log}_K(z)=\text{Log}_L(N_{K/L}z) \qquad (*)$$

Recall that $\Lambda_K := \text{Log}_K(\mathcal O_K^*)\subset\mathbb R$ is a lattice in $\mathbb R$ and that $v\in\mathcal O_K^*$ is a fundamental unit iff $\text{Log}_K(v)$ is a generator of that lattice. The same holds for $\Lambda_L := \text{Log}_L(\mathcal O_L^*)\subset\mathbb R$.

From $(*)$  we see that $\Lambda_K\subset\Lambda_L$. Since $N_{K/L}(1+\zeta)=2+\sqrt3 = u_1$ is a fundamental unit of $\mathcal O_K^*$, we thus see that $\Lambda_K=\Lambda_L$ and that $1+\zeta$ is a fundamental unit.

[With a bit of inspection one can check that your description of $\mathcal O_K^*$ gives every unit exactly once - it's not explicit in the question, but I guess it's still there implicitly.]